# Does Christianity have any other books besides the Bible that the disciples use for following?

Tags: bible, global-christianity

Does Christianity have any other book beside Bible which narrate stories of the Jesus and Moses and is considered auspicious or sacred? Are there any other such books other than Bible which kind of augments/completes the Bible? In Islam there is the Quran (Bible) and then hadith books which narrates stories of the prophets.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that no _one_ book besides the Bible will be accepted by _all_ Christians.  I used to think [_Mere Christianity_](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5246/914) was a candidate, but I've learned that even it is controversial in some circles.  I've voted to close the question, since it really should be scoped to which "brand" of Christianity you are interested in.  As it is, this is pretty much a poll.

Comment: @JonEricson I mentioned Quran and Hadith as comparison. I am not looking for publication. Something that was written along side Bible or in those times which can be used for learning about Christianity and is considered holy.

Comment: @Learner then the answer is likely a flat "no." I'd encourage you to do some research and ask specific questions instead of general ones. If you're actually interested in learning as your username indicates this would be an excellent way to start.

Comment: The Book of Enoch was referenced by St. Jude in his epistle, it references the burial of Moses and is not part of any Christian Bible that I know of.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @PeterTurner I meant something that is considered holy that is not divine but adds to bible, narrates stories about Jesus Christ and can be used to strengthen knowledge and faith.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on which branch of Christianity you're asking about.

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints (Mormons) recognize the Book of Mormon, the Pearl of Great Price, and the Doctrine and Covenants.  They also believe in continuing revelation.

Jehovah's Witnesses use the periodic publications of the Watchtower as authoritative.

The Catholic Church recognizes the Deuterocanon as part of the Bible, which most other Christian faiths do not.

The Community of Christ, formerly Reorganized Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints, recognizes the Book of Mormon, the Doctrine and Covenants, and the Revised Common Lectionary.

Seventh Day Adventists use the writings of Ellen White.

For a more comprehensive summary, see [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripture#Christianity)

Comment: That's about as good an answer as we are likely to get on the question as it's currently phrased.  Well done!

Comment: No I am not talking about any recent book, I have seen watchtower :) I am specifically asking about a book that was written some 1500 years ago or so that is considered authentic and is considered a holy book, preferably by all brands of Christianity.

Comment: @Learner:  Any particular book you had in mind?

Comment: @Learner Then the answer is "No."  The Bible is the one and only.

Comment: I have no idea, this is a question.

Comment: @Narnian that is what my question is about

Comment: Not to nitpick, but in this case one ought to acknowledge regarding the "apocrypha" that "Most other Christian faiths" = a minority of Christians. (And encompasses the Orthodox Church as well.)

Comment: @Learner: We do expect people to do a little seeking around before asking questions here.  Literally typing your question into [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Does+Christianity+have+any+other+books+besides+the+Bible+that+the+disciples+use+for+following) turned up as the top result, Wikipedia's excellent article on the [New Testament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament).  (Startlingly, it also turns up this question!)  We don't expect you to read _everything_ out there, but a little skimming would have made this a better question.

Comment: @JonEricson can you give me *any* link via google that answers my question?

Comment: Changed "Apocrypha" to "Deuterocanon" as there are multiple senses to the word "Apocrypha"

Comment: The Catholic church, Eastern orthodox church and oriental orthodox church all accept the deuterocanon. That represents the vast majority of the Christian world. Only the protestants reject the deuteros.

Answer (score 1):

For many centuries, *The Didache* would have qualified.  Additionally, today, many denominations use a Prayer Book or a Missal as an aide to the practice of the faith, but as far as doctrine goes, no - it's "The Bible," as defined by the sect.

Answer (score 0):

You could argue that the New Testament itself is the "other book" in addition to the Old Testament which is based either on the Masoretic text or the Septuagint depending on the tradition.